# How to access components data in component content with Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives, transclusion

While developing my first small angular 2 single page application I run into a problem. After two days of google and try-n-error you are my last hope.

Basically I have a repeated (ngFor) "group" component with multiple "listitem" components in it. A listitem is just some text with a checkbox.

The listitems are passed by content projection. Now I can display messages depending on how many listitems are selected using the slots for content projection.

```
    <group
      *ngFor="#item of List1; #i = index"
      [title]="item">

      <listitem 
        *ngFor="#item2 of List2; #k = index"
        [title]="item2"
        [selectionobject]="List3[ k ]">
        click to select
      </listitem>

      <div slot-noselect>
          <span>Select items as you like.</span>
      </div>
      <div slot-anyselect>
        <span>You have selected at least one item in the group.</span>

        <!-- In the following line "selobjects" is never set.
             It is a property of the group component class.
             Is it possible to access this here? -->
        <span *ngFor="#obj of selobjects; #l = index">
          You selected: {{ obj }}
        </span>

      </div>
    </group>
```

I'd like to display a list of all selected items (or even a count) and do that not in the group-component but in the group-component's content.

You can find the working code in plunker. Uncomment the section to see that it is not working.

https://plnkr.co/edit/hk7Naft1eseZFBOrME3i?p=preview

The basic question remains: Is components data accessible from projected content somehow?

Thanks for any help in advance.